# Spyware behaviour information

Tags: security

As part of trying to describe the threat posed by spyware and how to mitigate it I've been looking for information on how the various common spyware trojans currently in the wild capture password data. My best guess is that they either log keystrokes, intercept browser submissions or intercept GUI messages.

I'd like some more definitive information though and haven't been able to find it. Where would I find this sort of analysis?

Answer (score 0):

Most of malwares (I mean advanced ones) are written in ASM or C++. A lot of them use Windows high level APIs to hook keyboard key pressing activities among with current window when user pressed key.

For example for keyboard activity mostly they use `SetWindowsHookEx` function with `WH_KEYBOARD_LL` hook

Also they use GetActiveWindow API in order to detect current active window's title. So in keyloggers, mostly you'll see something like this:

```
[Gmail - Google Chrome Browser]
testuser@gmail.com {TAB} testpassword
```

So the person who receives the keylogs will read it as you can see above.

Another method is injecting some specially writted DLLs or extensions in browsers, I've seen it mostly for Internet explorer, they use BHO DLLs in order to receive ALL GET/POST data, so you don't need any actively running EXE file, just a DLL which runs as you open Internet explorer and the DLL will send directly all your POST/GET data as it is to hacker's server. It's mostly done in same time and BHO doesn't store anything (mostly) and sends same POST/GET data you've sent to your bank in same time to hacker's server. But other keyloggers mostly store keylogs until it reaches a size, for example 5kb, then trojan submits the keylog to hacker.

There is some also "not so common" tricks to capture keystrokes and that is having a low level driver which runs in ring-0 (kernel mode) and captures keyboard data, it's more sophisticated and hard to detect, but also hard for hacker to use, you need another co-operative ring-3 (user-mode) application to get current window, current keyboard layout (English, Chinese, Arabic, etc.) in same time as kernel receives keyboard, because without knowing keyboard layout and window which user pressed those keys, it will be "almost" useless.

I've also seen an "unprofessional" way of capturing key strokes, that's using `GetAsynKeyState` API. They mostly write a loop function and they capture key events by calling this API every 100 milliseconds (for example).

So I think I've covered a lot of techniques which keyloggers use to capture pressed keys, if you have more specific question, just let me know.